# How to check when a std::vector changes state from empty to non-empty and the other way around?

Tags: c++

I want to generate an event when the `vector` changes state from empty to non-empty or from non-empty to empty.

What is the easiest way to check this ?

Comment: Wrap it into a handmade observable vector. But you can't fire events in c++ anyway.

Comment: To check it's size? `vector::size()`. And when do you use your vector? I would rather catch that than observing the size of it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with details about what your actual problem is, what your proposed solution will achieve, and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: `if(myvector.empty()) { empty_event(); } else { not_empty.event(); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class that wraps a vector.  In insert remove operations, add checks for your transition.

Write or find an event framework.  Fire said events when you want them to occur.  Subscribe where you want to recieve.

`vector` is a light weight class that solves the problem of a dynamic, resizable array of contiguous elements well.  It does not contain event hooks: `std` does not make you pay for things you do not use (and most use cases do not require event hooks).